# Mi archivo de salida esta vacio usando mysqldump

Tags: crontab

Tengo un script con permisos de ejecución, lectura y escritura en 777:

```
mysqldump -u ivanchido -h 216.70.69.90 --password=Cris3979@@@ bdivan > respaldo
```

lo que hace este comando es crear una copia de respaldo en el archivo "respaldo" (sin comillas)

Ahora puse este mismo archivo en cron para que se ejecute cada 30 minutos

```
*/30 * * * * sh /Users/ivancaballerocano/ojalacorajes
```

le puse como pueden ver su ruta completa, la situación es que si el comando mysqldump lo ejecuto en la terminal tal y como lo ven todo funciona correctamente, pero si lo pongo en el cron... ahí lo único que pasa es que SI me crea el archivo "respaldo" (sin comillas) pero está vacio, no le pone nada.
NO encuentro la razón, alguna orientación?

Comment: Prueba poniendo el usuario y la clave entre comillas simples, algo así: `mysqldump -u 'ivanchido' -h 216.70.69.90 --password='Cris3979@@@' bdivan > respaldo`

Comment: ok lo probaré, gracias

Comment: vaya, parece que si funcionó....pero por que las tengo que poner entre comillas en el script y en comando directo en la terminal no es necesario???

Comment: Por decirlo de algún modo en el script, a diferencia de la línea de comandos, el usuario y la clave son considerados como una variable, por ese motivo debes ponerlo entre comillas en el script. Sea como sea, no es una buena práctica poner directamente usuario y password en la línea de comandos, porque esos datos quedarán guardados en el historial de comandos y usuarios con menos privilegios o intrusos, examinando esos archivos, podrán obtener esos datos y explotarlos. Deberías guardar usuario y password en el archivo de configuración.

Comment: Para más detalles sobre la seguridad [revisa la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html). En [esta respuesta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227657) puedes ver un ejemplo de configuración donde pones usuario, password y host.